# Adding meta tags to individual Blogger posts

Tags: blogger

I want to add meta tags and keywords for individual posts in Blogger. Is this possible or does it only work for the whole blog?

I'm trying to see if adding meta data per post will have any effect on their search engine rankings.

Comment: The only relevant part left was about adding in the meta tags. SEO would be off topic.

Answer (score 6):

1. Login to Blogger account.
2. Navigate to Design > Edit HTML
3. Click on Download Full Template for your security purpose.
4. Check the Expand Widget Templates box then..
5. Add the following in the `<head>` section of your Blogger template. Enter this code below the Home Page code above you have just entered:

   ```
    <b:if cond='data:blog.url == "http://url of your post"'>
     <meta content='keywords pertaining to your post' name='keywords'/>
     <meta content='crafted description of your post' name='description'/>
    </b:if>
   ```

Here is an example of optimized meta tags for this post:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "http://www.blogger-tricks.com/2011/11/how-to-add-meta-tags-in-every-blogger.html"'>
<meta content='meta tags,optimize blogger,blogger SEO,search engine optimization, blogspot,blogger,blogspot.com,blogger.com,blogging,blog' name='keywords'/>
<meta content='Improve SEO by adding meta tags to your Blogger Blogspot blog. Step by step tutorial shows you how to add meta tags to the home page and a single post' name='description'/>
</b:if>
```

1. Add your post URL, keywords and description. To find the URL of your post navigate to the post's page and copy the link showing in the address bar of your browser including the `http://` prefix
2. Click on the Save Template button.
3. To check your description you can use the view source in your browser once you have navigated to the post page or a meta tag analyzer

<sub>Note: This method is suitable if you have a few key posts that you want to ensure you get maximum traffic on. If you have a lot of posts this manual method would be very tedious.</sub>

Source: [Add Meta Tags in your Blogger posts](http://www.blogger-tricks.com/2011/11/how-to-add-meta-tags-in-every-blogger.html)